# Approach on how to pass data to MongoDB with Spring Data

Tags: java, mongodb, dao

im trying to build a little Webapplication as a project for myself.
The purpose of the app is that a user can save his ToDos in a database (secured by a login).

I've successfully set up the MongoDB in the CloudAtlas already, because I'd like to learn more about MongoDB.
I've also already made a successfull connection in my little application. 
I've also have the spring-login form sucessfully setup with the SecurityConfiguration

Right now im using a static list as "database" for my example data which i want to switch out with my MongoDB.

My question now is:
What are some best practices when working with MongoDB?
I've read plenty of buzzwords like DAO, Morphia, Spring Data etc and im confused on how i have to develop the methods that save and update the database in a practical way.

In theory, I want to use spring forms and tags to give me input data from the user, which i want to persist in the database. But right now, im just confused on where to start

MongoDB Conncetion

```java
package com.mschm.Database;

import org.bson.Document;

import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

public class DatabaseConnection {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(
                "mongodb+srv://<myUser>:<myPassword>@cluster0-1fduk.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority");

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");

        MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("Provision");
        MongoCollection collection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("salesinformation");

        Document document = new Document("desc", "Todo 2");
        document.append("isDone", "false");


        collection.insertOne(document);

    }
```

SecurityConfig

```java
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("Marvin").password("123")
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/", "/*todo*/**").access("hasRole('USER')").and()
                .formLogin();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use spring data jpa. You will need to create repository which will implement or extends spring data repositories

Comment: do you have an example of another stack thread or github repo ? / documentation?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gildasdarex/saggie-commons

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using morphia along with Spring. It is much easier to work with and you can use simple annotations to handle CRUD operations. You can use the @PathVariable and implement path variables so that you can properly manage what to do with the user inputs.